# Decimal.ToDouble Vs CType(x, Double) What is recommended/preferred

Tags: .net, vb.net, casting, double, type-conversion

I aim to convert a `Decimal` returned from a `NumericUpDown` control to a `Double`.

I can use either

```
MyDouble = Convert.ToDouble(MyDecimal)
```

or

```
MyDouble = CType(MyDecimal, Double)
```

or, according to MSDN `Decimal` has a `ToDouble` method, so I thought:

```
MyDouble = MyDecimal.ToDouble
```

What is the preferred/recommended method and why does the last option give me an error for an unspecified argument?

WRT the first part of that question, if it is a case that different conversion methodologies are supposed to be used for different types of objects, is there some place (preferably MSDN) where the information as to which approach for which object/requirement can be referenced?

Comment: The error you are getting with `MyDecimal.ToDouble` is because `ToDouble` is a shared method and not an instance method. What you need is `MyDouble = Decimal.ToDouble(MyDecimal)`. I too find the variety of conversion methods rather bewildering.

Comment: You forgot `DirectCast(MyDecimal, Double)`

Comment: Also `CDbl(MyDecimal)`.

Comment: @MattWilko & JoelCoehoorn Havent seen those ones before, drat!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably worth a read is [this page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa289509) (Conversion Functions, CType, DirectCast, and System.Convert Section).

The answer to your question is "It depends". For example it states on that page that

> The exact method call or IL instructions generated depends on the
>   expression against which the conversion is being applied. Some
>   conversions are optimized away, such as CInt(123.45) which is replaced
>   with the integer constant 123 in the IL. This is an example where
>   using the Visual Basic Runtime results in **better** performance than
>   using the System namespace

But its recommendation at the end however is:

> **Recommendation**: For most conversions, use the intrinsic language
>   conversion keywords (including **CType**) for brevity and clarity and to
>   allow compiler optimizations when converting between types. Use
>   **DirectCast** for converting Object to String and for extracting value
>   types boxed in Object variables when the embedded type is known (that
>   is, coercion is not necessary).

Comment: Matt, Following your link, I've used `Dim d As Double = CDbl(MyNumericUpDown.Value)`

Answer (score -1):

In terms of efficiency CType is not the best. 
It is more accepted to use Convert.ToDouble() as it is generally more efficient.

As mentioned in a comment above, the .ToDouble is a shared method so you must go:

```
    Dim test As Decimal = 2.22
    Dim myDouble As Double

    myDouble = Convert.ToDouble(test)

    myDouble = Decimal.ToDouble(test)
```

Either of the above methods will work to change the type.

Comment: And yet the [MSDN documentation of CType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) states that "CType is compiled inline, which means that the conversion code is part of the code that evaluates the expression. In some cases, the code runs faster because no procedures are called to perform the conversion."

Comment: What's the difference between the `ToDouble` and the implicit cast? do they not both do the same thing? Or even between the `Decimal.ToDouble`and the `Convert.ToDouble`?

Comment: @Blackwood This is true, that is why I said it was generally more efficient to use Convert.ToDouble() or another method because yes in some cases CType will be quicker.

Comment: Fixed my post from being in c#

Comment: `CType` is **not** "leftover" from VB6.  You may be confusing it with the other C??? methods like `CDec`, `Cint`, `Cstr` etc.  It is the wrong method for the OP, but your explanation is incorrect.

Comment: @Plutonix: I would be interested in reading a comparison of the different conversion methods or anything that would help me know which to use when. Do you know of one (or care to write one)?

Comment: @Plutonix I removed my comment about CType being leftover now.

Comment: All of the `C_()` casts are actually _operators_ rather than functions. They're just implemented with function semantics. While I really loathe the vb6-era functions like `LEN()` and `MID()` that are available in vb.net, the operators are just part of the language.

Comment: @Blackwood, there are some good tidbits in a [general MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx).  I am inclined to prefer `Convert.ToXXX` but the VB ones like `CInt` are better in some cases (more inlining, and handles situations which crash `System.Convert`).